# QCA blowfish decryption fails

Tags: qt, encryption, blowfish

I'm trying to use QCA to encrypt/decrypt files.
When i use this code to encrypt, everything works fine (or seems to, at least).
But when i try to decrypt, the process() method returns an empty SecureArray.
Does anyone have an idea why and/or how to fix it?

```
void FileCrypto::crypt(QByteArray key, bool crypt){
    QCA::Initializer init;
    open();
    Cipher cipher = initializeCipher(key, crypt);
    QTextStream in(source);                                            //lecture ligne par ligne
    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        SecureArray secureData = line.toAscii().data();                        //securise les donnees
        if(!crypt)
            QString temp = QString::fromAscii(secureData.toByteArray().toHex());
        qDebug() << "Données lues : " << secureData.data();
        SecureArray cryptedData = cipher.process(secureData);                  //(de)crypte les donnees
        qDebug() << "Données cryptées :" << cryptedData.data();
        destination->write(cryptedData.data());                    //ecris dans le nouveau fichier

    }
    close();
}

void FileCrypto::open() throw (QString){
    if(!source->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)
        || !destination->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        throw QString("Impossible d'ouvrir les fichiers cibles.");
    }
}

void FileCrypto::close(){
    source->close();
    destination->close();
}

Cipher FileCrypto::initializeCipher(QByteArray akey, bool crypt){
    QCA::InitializationVector iv;
    Direction direction;
    SymmetricKey key = SymmetricKey(akey);
    iv = InitializationVector(akey);

    if(crypt){
        direction = Encode;
    }else{
        direction = Decode;
    }

    return Cipher(QString("blowfish"),Cipher::CBC,
                  Cipher::DefaultPadding, direction, key, iv);
}
```